# Inserting string between two known strings with sed or awk

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I've used sed a bit before in the past for updating strings but I haven't been successful with inserting a string in between two known strings.

I attempted to use this but it didn't update anything.

```
sed -e '/^\dest="download",\$/,/^\action="store_true",\/ ^xyz .*/a default=True/'
```

This is the block of code that needs to be edited within a script. There is spacing/tabbing that I would like to maintain if possible.

```
    parser.add_option(
        "--download",
        dest="download",
        action="store_true",
        help="Download preinstalled packages from PyPI.",
    )
```

The inserted string is `default=True,`

```
    parser.add_option(
        "--download",
        dest="download",
        default=True,
        action="store_true",
        help="Download preinstalled packages from PyPI.",
    )
```

If someone does answer this using awk I'd like to understand how the function works so I'd appreciate a broken down explanation.

Answer (score 0):

File: `parser.awk`

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
# Above line is the shebang line and it's always the first line

# First string found?
/dest="download"/ {
    # Print current line
    print
    # Set the first string found flag
    flag = 1
    # Next line!
    next
}

# First string flagged AND second string found?
flag == 1 && /action="store_true"/ {
    # Print new line
    print "        default=True,"
    # Print current line
    print
    # Unflag first string
    flag = 0
    # Next line!
    next
}

# Other lines
{
    # Print current line
    print
}
```

With executable modes:

```bash
chmod 755 parser.awk
```

AWK script used like that:

```bash
./parser.awk file.txt
```

## UPDATE

One line sed:

```bash
sed '/dest="download"/{x;s/.*/./;x};/action="store_true"/{x;/^.$/{x;s/^/        default=True,\n/;x};s/^/./;x}' file.txt
```